# Absorb equal strings onto the same pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm making a program that reads a text file composed by strings, each one on a line. Basically I do this:

```
...
char* name;
char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE); //size is a defined constant in the header
while(fgets(buffer, SIZE, pf)){ //pf is the opened stream
    name = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE);
    strcpy(name, strtok(buffer, "\n"));
    manipulate(name); //call an extern function
}
```

Function *manipulate* is declared in this manner:

```
void manipulate(void* ptr);
```

The problem is that in this way two equal strings will have different memory addresses so they will recognized as two different elements from *manipulate* function.

How can I make them recognized as a single element?

Comment: Make a list (could be singly linked list), when you obtain the string from the line, compare it with `strcmp()` with each string from the list. If the strcmp function never returned 0 then this string is unique to this point.

Comment: Since `fgets` reads line by line, there's no need for `strtok` unless you're using that to strip off a newline?

Comment: Unless this code has to be ridiculously portable, to like computers made by aliens, `sizeof(char)` is a bit paranoid and you can just alloc `SIZE` bytes. If you like the formality of the size vs number as being expressed clearly then maybe you should use [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) instead.

Comment: Read the whole file into buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the strings in a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)), a data type which stores no repeated values and is fast to search. Basically it's a hash table where the key is the string and the value doesn't matter.

You can write your own hash table, it's a good exercise, but for production you're better off using an existing one like from [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-hash-table-new). It already has convenience methods for using a hash table as a set. While we're at it, we can use their [`g_strchomp()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strchomp) and [`g_strdup()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>

int main () {
    // Initialize our set of strings.
    GHashTable *set = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);

    // Allocate a line buffer on the stack.
    char line[1024];

    // Read lines from stdin.
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        // Strip the newline.
        g_strchomp(line);

        // Look up the string in the set.
        char *string = g_hash_table_lookup(set, line);
        if( string == NULL ) {
            // Haven't seen this string before.
            // Copy it, using only the memory we need.
            string = g_strdup(line);
            // Add it to the set.
            g_hash_table_add(set, string);
        }

        printf("%p - %s\n", string, string);
    }
}
```

And here's a quick demonstration.

```
$ ./test
foo
0x60200000bd90 - foo
foo
0x60200000bd90 - foo
bar
0x60200000bd70 - bar
baz
0x60200000bd50 - baz
aldskflkajd
0x60200000bd30 - aldskflkajd
aldskflkajd
0x60200000bd30 - aldskflkajd
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to install glib packet? I searched a lot and found this: **sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev**.. I made it but actually don't works

Comment: @Lorenzo It's probably that you need to include the glib header files and link to its shared libraries. Simplest way to do that is to use [`pkg-config`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/pkg-config). Set `CFLAGS += pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0` and `LDFLAGS += pkg-config --libs glib-2.0` in your Makefile. Here's [an example Makefile that I use for compiling test code](https://gist.github.com/schwern/0b806ea424ab70aa8f0c6471aa224b4a).

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed have *two* strings then they necessarily have different addresses, regardless of whether their contents are the same.  It sounds like you want to keep track of the strings you've already read, so as to avoid / merge duplicates.  That starts with the "keeping track" part.

Evidently, then, you need some kind of data structure in which to record the strings you've already read.  You have many choices for that, and they have different advantages and disadvantages.  If the number of distinct strings you'll need to handle is relatively small then a simple array or linked list could suffice, but if it is large enough then a hash table will provide much better performance.

With that in hand, you check each newly-read string against the previously read ones and act accordingly.

Comment: Then if two string matches he can concatenate them with `strcat` if he wants two strings to share the same address. He can separate the strings with a delimiter like `\n` or `\0` and a hash table will definitely serve well accessing those strings. He can also use GString as it expands "automatically" when a string is added, to save effort.

Comment: Well no, @Edenia, if he concatenated the strings' contents (supposing there was enough space) then he wouldn't have either one any more.  He would have the concatenated contents, which are different from the individual strings'.  And the sub-parts would *not* have the same address.  Besides, that approach is wasteful.  If he wants to track how many times he's seen a given string then he would be better off keeping an integer counter for each one.

Comment: This is not true. As long as it ends with a null it is considered a valid string, the fact that it is located in memory address after previous string doesn't make it not string. Consider this: [s][t][r][1][\0][s][t][r][2][\0] here `str1+5` is a string, not even a substring. Whether he holds a reference to all those strings is another subject. Also yes, they will of course not share magically the same address, but they can be accessed by virtue of the same offset address.

Comment: Read again, @Edenia.  I never said that anything was not a string.  I said that the concatenated result would be a string with *different contents* than the (either) original, and that if you consider the substrings then they do not have the same address as each other.

Comment: I don't see how the result is a string with different contents than the original. The null determinate "end of string x" So you are not building/formatting a string. You just allocate enough memory to hold as many strings as needed, then concatenate them and delimit them with '\0'

Comment: @Edenia, if you copy a second string into unused but allocated space after the terminator of the first then yes, *in that one variation* on what you suggested, and only that one, two separate strings with the same content remain.  And that leaves the OP with exactly the same problem he already had, unless he just ignores one of them, in which case what was the point?